# MySQL: Join distinct rows of two tables in a certain order?

Tags: mysql, join, distinct

I have a list of inventory units and sale transactions that I want to, (1) join by unit SKU, and (2) associate ONE transaction to ONE inventory unit in first-in-first-out order by date. I'm having trouble with the second part.

The best I can come up with is:

```
SELECT `units`.`unit_date`, `units`.`unit_id`, `trans`.`tran_date`, `trans`.`tran_id`, `units`.`unit_sku` FROM `units`
    INNER JOIN `trans`
        ON `trans`.`unit_sku` = `units`.`unit_sku`
GROUP BY `trans`.`tran_id`, `trans`.`unit_sku`
ORDER BY `units`.`unit_date` asc, `trans`.`tran_date` asc
;
```

`units` table:

```
unit_date  | unit_id | unit_sku
2015-06-01 | 1       | U1KLM
2015-06-02 | 2       | U1KLM
2015-06-03 | 3       | U2QRS
2015-06-04 | 4       | U2QRS
2015-06-05 | 5       | U1KLM
```

`trans` table:

```
tran_date  | tran_id | unit_sku
2015-06-11 | A       | U2QRS
2015-06-12 | B       | U1KLM
2015-06-13 | C       | U1KLM
2015-06-14 | D       | U2QRS
2015-06-15 | E       | U1KLM
```

The **desired result** is one `tran_id` to be joined to one `unit_id` of the `unit_sku` by earliest-to-latest order of `unit_date`:

```
unit_date  | unit_id | tran_date  | tran_id | unit_sku
2015-06-01 | 1       | 2015-06-12 | B       | U1KLM
2015-06-02 | 2       | 2015-06-13 | C       | U1KLM
2015-06-03 | 3       | 2015-06-11 | A       | U2QRS
2015-06-04 | 4       | 2015-06-14 | D       | U2QRS
2015-06-05 | 5       | 2015-06-15 | E       | U1KLM
```

The **query (undesired) result** joins `tran_id` only to the `unit_id` of the earliest occurrence of `unit_sku`:

```
unit_date  | unit_id | tran_date  | tran_id | unit_sku
2015-06-01 | 1       | 2015-06-12 | B       | U1KLM
2015-06-01 | 1       | 2015-06-13 | C       | U1KLM
2015-06-01 | 1       | 2015-06-15 | E       | U1KLM
2015-06-03 | 3       | 2015-06-11 | A       | U2QRS
2015-06-03 | 3       | 2015-06-14 | D       | U2QRS
```

Any ideas on how to do get the desired result? In this setup, only `unit_date` and `tran_date` are sortable; the rest are randomly generated.

Repro script:

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `units`;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `trans`;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `units` (`unit_date` date, `unit_id` char(1) , `unit_sku` char(5), PRIMARY KEY(`unit_id`));
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `trans` (`tran_date` date, `tran_id` char(1) , `unit_sku` char(5), PRIMARY KEY(`tran_id`));

INSERT INTO `units` (`unit_date`, `unit_id`, `unit_sku`) VALUES
    ('2015-06-01', '1', 'U1KLM')
    , ('2015-06-02', '2', 'U1KLM')
    , ('2015-06-03', '3', 'U2QRS')
    , ('2015-06-04', '4', 'U2QRS')
    , ('2015-06-05', '5', 'U1KLM')
;

INSERT INTO `trans` (`tran_date`, `tran_id`, `unit_sku`) VALUES
    ('2015-06-11', 'A', 'U2QRS')
    , ('2015-06-12', 'B', 'U1KLM')
    , ('2015-06-13', 'C', 'U1KLM')
    , ('2015-06-14', 'D', 'U2QRS')
    , ('2015-06-15', 'E', 'U1KLM')
;

SELECT `units`.`unit_date`, `units`.`unit_id`, `trans`.`tran_date`, `trans`.`tran_id`, `units`.`unit_sku` FROM `units`
    INNER JOIN `trans`
        ON `trans`.`unit_sku` = `units`.`unit_sku`
GROUP BY `trans`.`tran_id`, `trans`.`unit_sku`
ORDER BY `units`.`unit_date` asc, `trans`.`tran_date` asc
;
```

Comment: Can you guarantee that there is always a 1 to 1 record relationship in these two tables?

Also, what DB are you using?

Comment: One unit can have multiple transactions -- for example, if a unit is returned and then sold for the second time. But most commonly will be 1-to-1. Regarding what DB, I'm using a homegrown solution on MySQL 5.6.24, if that's what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for: (This is assuming that 1 to 1 relationship)

```
SET @UNITRN := 0;
SET @TRANSRN :=0;
SELECT A.`unit_date`, A.`unit_id`, B.`tran_date`, B.`tran_id`, A.`unit_sku` FROM (SELECT @UNITRN := @UNITRN + 1 AS ROWNUM, UNIT_DATE, UNIT_ID, UNIT_SKU FROM UNITS ORDER BY UNIT_SKU, UNIT_DATE ASC) A
JOIN (SELECT @TRANSRN := @TRANSRN + 1 AS ROWNUM, TRAN_DATE, TRAN_ID, UNIT_SKU FROM TRANS ORDER BY UNIT_SKU, TRAN_DATE ASC) B
ON A.UNIT_SKU = B.UNIT_SKU
AND A.ROWNUM = B.ROWNUM
ORDER BY A.UNIT_DATE ASC
```

Comment: Yes, this works well for the 1-to-1. I'm playing around with throwing a 1-to-n at it. I'll need to look at how else my data is joined, but this gets me started.